# Pipeline Sklearn ( missing basic ) Predictions Error

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline

Need some assistance, I am kind of stuck at the concept of implementing **pipelines using sklearn**. This dataset is KC Housing Dataset from Kaggle. I am trying to build a simple Linear regression , using Pipelines. However, I am missing something quite basic from the concept as I am unable to get past the error pasted at the bottom of this post. Please advise, its really appreciated.  This is the complete code for this, feel free to mend the code where necessary.

```
**ERROR:**
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/JBook/Software/PythonProjects/KCH/OneFi.py", line 123, in <module>
    main()
  File "/media/JBook/Software/PythonProjects/KCH/OneFi.py", line 118, in main
    predictions_some_data = lin_reg.predict(some_data_prepared)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sklearn/linear_model/base.py", line 256, in predict
    return self._decision_function(X)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sklearn/linear_model/base.py", line 241, in _decision_function
    dense_output=True) + self.intercept_
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/extmath.py", line 135, in safe_sparse_dot
    ret = a * b
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/base.py", line 387, in __mul__
    raise ValueError('dimension mismatch')
ValueError: dimension mismatch
```

PS: Problem I am facing in this is at the almost end of this code
***"predictions_some_data = lin_reg.predict(some_data_prepared)"***

```
import pandas as pd
import os, sys
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import data_visualize
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedShuffleSplit
import dataPrep
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from pandas.plotting import scatter_matrix
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
from sklearn.pipeline import FeatureUnion

**## Loading the data**
KC_housing_path = "/media/JBook/Software/PythonProjects/KCH/datasets"
def load_housing_data(housing_path=KC_housing_path):
    '''if not os.path.isfile("datasets/kc_house_data.csv"):
        print("Check file location, program exiting..")
    else:
        csv_path = os.path.join(housing_path, "kc_house_data.csv")
        print("reading csv file ...")
        return pd.read_csv(csv_path)'''
    try:
        csv_path = os.path.join(housing_path, "kc_house_data.csv")
        print("reading csv file -->")
        return pd.read_csv(csv_path)


    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("Check file location, program exiting ...")
        sys.exit()

**### Defining 2 classes for custom transformers**
class DataFrameSelector(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, attributeNames):
        self.attributes = attributeNames
        # print('\n In constructor', self.attributes)

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        # print("__DF Fit Method:\n", (X[self.attributes].values).shape)
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        # print("__Transform Method:\n", (X[self.attributes].values).shape)
        return X[self.attributes].values


class LabelBinarizerPipelineFriendly(LabelBinarizer):
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        # print("LB-->X.shape", X.shape)
        """this would allow us to fit the model based on the X input."""
        super(LabelBinarizerPipelineFriendly, self).fit(X)

    def transform(self, X, y=None):
        # print("LB-Transform-X.shape", X.shape)
        return super(LabelBinarizerPipelineFriendly, self).transform(X)

    def fit_transform(self, X, y=None):
        # print("LB-FIT_TRANSFORM-X.Shape", X.shape)
        return super(LabelBinarizerPipelineFriendly, self).fit(X).transform(X)


def main():
    # Loading House data
    housing = load_housing_data()
    housing_labels = housing['price']
    # Removing not needed features & label ( price)
    rem_attributes = ['id', 'date', 'price']
    housing_col_removed = housing.drop(rem_attributes, axis=1, inplace=False)

**### Splitting the data** 
    train_set, test_set = train_test_split(housing_col_removed, test_size=0.3, random_state=42)

**#### Pipleline for numeric & categorical attribute transformations 
#### Adding median to missing values & making one hot vectors of categorical attributes**

    data_numeric = housing_col_removed.drop('ocean_proximity', axis=1, inplace=False)
    numeric_attrib = list(data_numeric)
    cat_attrib = ['ocean_proximity']

    num_pipeline = Pipeline([
        ('selector', DataFrameSelector(numeric_attrib)),
        ('imputing', Imputer(missing_values=0, strategy='median')),
    ])

    cat_pipeline = Pipeline([
        ('selector', DataFrameSelector(cat_attrib)),
        ('label_Bin', LabelBinarizerPipelineFriendly(sparse_output=True)),
    ])

    full_pipeline = FeatureUnion(transformer_list=[
        ('num_pipeline', num_pipeline),
        ('cat_pipeline', cat_pipeline),
    ])

**#### Fitting the linear regression model**
    # print('This housing data is passed to prepare\n', housing_col_removed.head())
    housing_prepared = dataPrep.prepData(housing_col_removed)
    lin_reg = LinearRegression()
    lin_reg.fit(housing_prepared, housing_labels)
    print('Housing Prepared Shape: \n', housing_prepared.shape)
    print('\t\t\t\t\************* Predictions from Linear Regression Are ***********\n',lin_reg.predict(housing_prepared))

**### Below section is trying to use some data (5 rows ) from whole data set to predict values** 

    some_data = housing_col_removed[:5]
    some_labels = housing_labels.iloc[:5]
    some_data_prepared = full_pipeline.fit_transform(some_data)
    print('\t\t\tSome Data Prepared is\n', some_data_prepared)
    predictions_some_data = lin_reg.predict(some_data_prepared)
    print('\t\t\t\t\************* Predictions from Linear Regression Are ***********\n', predictions_some_data)
    # print('\t\t\t\t\************* Labels Are ***********\n', list(some_labels))


main()
```

Comment: Why are you not calling `full_pipeline.fit()` on the data which is being fitted in the `lin_reg.fit()`?

Comment: Also, why are you calling `full_pipeline.fit_transform()` on the prediction data in place of `full_pipeline.transform()`? The fit_transform will forget all previously learnt data and fit again, so depending on your test data, `LabelBinarizerPipelineFriendly` will generate different features. Hence the mismatch.

Comment: Thanks Vivek, for prompt replies. Here are my comments & couple questions.

Comment: FYI - got the code to work. Issue was solved by using as suggested only transform function on test data & then predict function on lin_reg model. However, MSE is way off: which is a separate issues I need to look at.

Comment: 1. To your first question:  I am calling full_pipeline.fit_tansform, its just being called from another file->function( dataPrep.py->PrepData fn() )

lin_reg.fit model was applied to prepared data in the variable "housing_prepared"

Comment: 2. Very Important concept I am failing to understand: As you say the fit or fit_transform function will forget all trained data & re-fit this: where is this trained data residing, prepared by full_pipeline.fit_transform? Where is this trained data stored? Is it in some cache / variables? Reason I ask this is  because I don't see the learnt data being referred anywhere in my call to full_pipeline.predict() function on test data. Is it in "lin_reg" model variable?

Comment: 3. What do you mean by saying LabelBinarizerFriendly will generate different features, I think I am understanding the fact the features are added as the dimensions of the returned ND Array is wider. But I am trying to understand the concept behind it. Can you please shed some light on that or direct me to a URL explaining this? thanks.